# Script for replacing digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that has content as below

```
a      b     c    123.67989

aa   bb  cc   56789.38475

b    c   a    56789.3456

bb   cc  aa   0.12409124

c    a   b    0.0123123
```

I am trying to remove digits after the `.` in the each line. Is there is a way to do this using regular expressions in Python?
Code I wrote
f1 = open('filename.txt','r')

for line in f1:

```
    words = line.split()
    print(words[3])
```

I am trying retrieve last row information and I keep getting error list indices out of range

Comment: use `line.split('.')[0]`

Comment: Replacing or removing? If replacing, with what? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you should be appreciating OPs effort to post question :)

Comment: @Saleem should I? Did they put any in?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I clearly mentioned removing. I tried line.split() function to remove digits. What do you mean my what exactly is the problem

Comment: @Chris_Rands : Thanks. I understood where I was doing wrong. I used line.split(' '). instead of line.split(.).

Comment: Yes, and you also clearly wrote replacing in the title. Ok, then show a [mcve] of what you tried. I mean what is the problem with your code; what did you want it to do and what did it do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use regular expressions but maybe this helps:

```
text = "a      b     c    123.67989 \n" \
"aa   bb  cc   56789.38475 \n" \
"b    c   a    56789.3456 \n" \
"bb   cc  aa   0.12409124 \n" \
"c    a   b    0.0123123"

lines = text.splitlines()

for line in lines:
   line_without_digits = line.split('.')[0]
   print(line_without_digits)
```

**EDIT**

Example with first digit after ".":

```
text = "a      b     c    123.67989 \n" \
"aa   bb  cc   56789.38475 \n" \
"b    c   a    56789.3456 \n" \
"bb   cc  aa   0.12409124 \n" \
"c    a   b    0.0123123"

lines = text.splitlines()

for line in lines:
    line_split = line.split('.')
    line_without_digits = line_split[0] + "." + line_split[1][0]
    print(line_without_digits)
```

Comment: Is there is a way to get first digit after . ?

Comment: In the edit you have an example with first digit after .

Answer (score 0):

No regex here, either, but:

```
with open( "C:/TestFile.txt", 'r' ) as file:
   lines = file.readlines()

out_lines = []

out_file = open( "C:/TestFile2.txt", "w" )

for i in range( len( lines ) ):
   out_lines.append( lines[ i ].split( "." )[0] )

for line in out_lines:
   out_file.write( "%s\n" % line )
```

To access the numbers after the decimal, just access the second part of the split:

Python supports offset notation on strings, and you can access the second part of the split.

```
for i in range( len( lines ) ):
   parts = lines[ i ].split( "." )
   out_lines.append( parts[0] )
   first_decimal = parts[1][0]
```

Or, if your goal is to round the values in the 4th column, something like this may be what you want:

```
for i in range( len( lines ) ):
   parts = lines[i].split()

   if len( parts ) == 0:
      out_lines.append( "" )
      continue

   out_lines.append( parts[0].ljust( 5 ) + parts[1].ljust( 4 ) + parts[2].ljust( 5 ) + format( float( parts[3] ), '.1f' ) )
```

Comment: Is there is a way to get 1st digit after  .?

Comment: Python supports offset notation on strings, and you can access the second part of the split.

I updated my answer with sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Get only digits with one decimal value:

```
import re

text = """
a      b     c    123.67989

aa   bb  cc   56789.38475

b    c   a    56789.3456

bb   cc  aa   0.12409124

c    a   b    0.0123123
"""

digits = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d{1}', text)
print(digits)

# prints: ['123.6', '56789.3', '56789.3', '0.1', '0.0']
```